# Alfresco couldn't start. Why?

Tags: tomcat, postgresql, disk-space-utilization, jdbc, alfresco

I have alfresco on my VM. When I try to start alfresco I got an error "postgresql  could not be started" such as following :

```
/opt/alfresco/postgresql/scripts/ctl.sh : postgresql  could not be started
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/alfresco/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/alfresco/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/alfresco/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /opt/alfresco/java
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/alfresco/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar
/opt/alfresco/tomcat/scripts/ctl.sh : tomcat started
```

When I check it turns out harddisk capacity is full.

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1             7.4G  7.4G     0 100% /
none                 1001M  152K 1001M   1% /dev
none                 1005M     0 1005M   0% /dev/shm
none                 1005M   52K 1005M   1% /var/run
none                 1005M     0 1005M   0% /var/lock
/dev/sda3             9.2G  634M  8.1G   8% /var
```

I've put jdbc postgresql into /tomcat/lib. whether the full capacity of the harddisk on the VM it affects so alfresco become error or because of something else? and How do I fix it? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem will most likely be related to having a full disk but even if it's not something else will break because of it so tackle that first. Use the command

```
du --max-depth=1 / | sort -rn
```

to get a list of the files and directories and the disk space they use (in blocks). The higher up the list the more disk space being used. You can then use the same command to drill down through the filesystem to determine what is filling the disk. If for example you determine that /tomcat is the directory that contains the directories/files filling the disk then issue the command

```
du --maxdepth=1 /tomcat  | sort -rn
```

and so on until eventually you'll need to use `ls -l` to determine which files are the cause.

Once you know this you should be able to determine the appropriate action to take.